# Compact checkbox inputs

Tags: input-fields, checkboxes

How is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/crl/8h9amo6p/4/) in terms of usability?

[image]

It's maybe not obvious you can switch those elements, is it still an intuitive way to represent a checkbox input?

Comment: You might want to elaborate a bit more. Perhaps provide a screenshot of your solution together with the link. Perhaps an explanation of what you want to achieve. Some more context. I, for one, don't understand what your question is exactly.

Comment: if you don't understand from the fiddle, it means it's not really clear for every user, so thanks for your input

Comment: if it is not obvious, it is not usable.

Comment: I've added a screenshot to avoid link rot and future proof the question, if you feel it is unnecessary feel free to roll back (but risk being closed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably [add a hover state](http://uxmovement.com/forms/why-you-should-add-hover-effects-to-your-checkboxes/) and not have the background be a light grey when off, as that commonly denotes a [disabled input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qa6mH.png).

Also, a checkbox is commonly bordered. Not a must, but it's commonplace.